# Java : Best jdbc support?

Tags: java, mysql

A few years ago, JDBC was a little funny in some versions of sqlserver.  Is there a "best" jdbc driver out there ?  Like, is there a database [suspecting hsql or mysql] that is optimally suited for 100% java development with rdbms ?

Comment: The two questions are not the same. "What's the best JDBC driver for [any DBMS]?" is a good question. The second question makes less sense. Which one do you really want answered?

Comment: Are you thinking of the [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver? It was an excellent replacement for the Microsoft SQL Server driver that had a lot of problems back then.

Comment: World has moved much ahead. Now,  it seems, NoSQL is getting traction.

Comment: @Jayan how does that pertain to this question?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL. Nothing.. if Shasha wanted to check what really changed in database world.. one thing changed is increased use of no-sqls and ORM tools.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a database that is optimally suited for 100% java development with rdbms ?

Nope.

The whole *point* of a driver is to make an arbitrary database (the one the driver was written for) usable via JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has [some special tuning for  java.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chnine.htm) I am not sure if that translate to some special facilities for java. My experience is that first we pick a  database  and a suitable driver.  Then we live with whatever the driver offers.

I used jtds to connect to MS-SQL without any problems. (well, my programs just query and update relatively simple structures)